# Can not Parse EMV TAG Issuer Application Data 9F10

Tags: cryptography, tags, contactless-smartcard, emv, tlv

I have this Issuer Application Data I need to parse

Issuer Application Data = 06001103A020000A0100000000002221DFBB

When I parse I thing the Cryptogram Version is 0x11 = which is 17 (Is this right ?)

Secondly, when I look for documents online, I could not find any application cryptogram data creation flow regarding CV17 ?
Do I missing any document?

Answer (score 3):

It is Visa PayWave IAD Tag 0x9F10 and Contactless CVN=17.

```
---
# Cheef's parser.
# Copyright (C) 2008-2020 Alexander Shevelev. https://iso8583.info/
# lib   : "/lib/EMV/C3/" # Contactless Specifications for Payment Systems, Book C-3, Kernel 3
# tool  : "TV"

# stat  : 12 nodes, 1 lookup tables, 100.00% passed (4/4)

TV:#"9F1006001103A020000A0100********2221DFBB" # EMV C-3, Issuer Application Data (IAD)
- tag: "9F10"
- val:#"06001103A020000A0100********2221DFBB" # Issuer Application Data (IAD).
  - len: "06" #  // 6
  - DKI: "00" # Derivation Key Index (DKI)
  - CVN: "11" # Cryptogram Version Number (CVN) // 17 - CVN 17
  - CVR:#"03A02000" # Card Verification Results
    - len: "03" #  // 3
    - B02: "A0"
      # 10______ - bits 8-7, not supported
      # __10____ - bits 6-5, AC Returned in First GenAC - ARQC
    - B03: "20"
      # __1_____ - bit 6, Exceeded velocity checking counters
    - B04: "00"
  - IDD: "0A0100********2221DFBB" # Issuer Discretionary data
```